# Fortran Importerror that is linked with fortran

Tags: python, fortran, linker-errors, gfortran

I am trying to install [MCdisp](https://github.com/xin2zhang/MCDisp).
After successful compilation, I have ran the jupyter example file. I am getting the issue given below.

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-089f6b0dbc63> in <module>
      1 # Load dispersion modelling code
----> 2 from pydisp import disp

ImportError: /home/amit/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pydisp.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: _gfortran_transfer_character_write
```

I am using ubuntu 18.04
Till now, I understand that issue might be related with the link between Python and Fortran. But I am not sure the cause. I have attempted through several way through online search. But I am still stuck at the same place from where I started.

my attempt was based on `.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: _gfortran_transfer_character_write`

If my issue is resolved the It will import the disp from pydisp.

Comment: Do NOT open a new question when revising your current one. Use the edit button instead. DO read [tour], [ask] and [mcve], it is really important. Also, use proper tags and formatting, you should at the edits I made to your older version of the question and follow them. Delete one of the question versions and improve the other one, because it will likely be closed otherwise.